# facebook sdk compile error in xode6 beta

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk, ios8, xcode6

When i tried to build facebook sdk in xcode6 beta  i got the following error .its because of the conflict with name of Apple's non public selectors.

"Copy attribute on property 'description' doesn't match the propertyfor property named description in facebookopengraphobject.

Anyways to overcome this compile error.

Comment: I have got into the same problem. any solution would highly appreciated. the problem is in this property which was probably changed in ios8: @property (retain, nonatomic) id description;

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted this line :
@property (retain, nonatomic) id description;

that worked

Answer (score 0):

Seems like description becomes the native key words for iOS 8 now. Same issue for me.